# How to track Google AdSense statistics from Asyncrhonous code in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, adsense

I am using Google AdSense Ads in the **classic (synchronous)** way for 4 years.
I have linked my 3 websites (Google Analytics properties) to this AdSense account, in order to have statistics in Google Analytics.
Everything is working well.

Now, I am willing to **switch to the Asynchronous version of the AdSense code**, for loading speed optimization reasons.
That part is easy : I just have to grab the new code from my Google AdSense account.

By my question regards the following little Javascript code snippet I am currently using with **EACH** Synchronous (classic) Ad code : Is this snippet still needed ? ***This snippet is actually needed with the classic code to make sure that Google Analytics can get statistics for each Ad block***.

```
<script>
//Required because each adsense code nulls 'window.google_analytics_uacct' 
window.google_analytics_uacct="UA-0000000-0";

//Required because I'm using ._setDomainName in the Google Analytics code
google_analytics_domain_name="www.example.com";

//Here is the classic (synchronous) AdSense code
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0000000000000000";
google_ad_slot = "0000000000";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

I am about to use the following **Asynchronous code** from AdSense, and would like to know if I still need to include my snippet, or if I can now get rid of ?

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000000000"
     data-ad-slot="0000000000"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question, from my personal experience.

I have switched from the SYNCRHONOUS to the ASYNCRHONOUS Google AdSense code 2 weeks ago.

It appears that **these two following lines are NOT necessary anymore to get AdSense Earnings reported into Google Analytics**. WIthout these 2 lines, my revenue is well reported in Google Analytics.

Hope it helps !

```
window.google_analytics_uacct="UA-0000000-0";
google_analytics_domain_name="www.example.com";
```